# Signature verification failed

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, signature

I am trying to create a sign in transaction using the following code (using react wallet adapter):

```
const tx = new Transaction().add(
            // create nonce account
            SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: nonceAccount.publicKey,
            lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(NONCE_ACCOUNT_LENGTH),
            space: NONCE_ACCOUNT_LENGTH,
            programId: SystemProgram.programId,
            
            }),
            // init nonce account
            SystemProgram.nonceInitialize({
            noncePubkey: nonceAccount.publicKey, // nonce account pubkey
            authorizedPubkey: publicKey, // nonce account auth
            }),
            new TransactionInstruction({
                keys: [{ pubkey: publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }],
                data: Buffer.from("Data to send in transaction", "utf-8"),
                programId: new PublicKey("MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr"),
            }),

        );
        tx.feePayer = publicKey;

        const {
            context: { slot: minContextSlot },
            value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
          } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();
          
        try {
            const signature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection, {
                minContextSlot,
                skipPreflight: true,
                signers: [],
                preflightCommitment: 'processed',
               
              });
              console.log({ blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight, signature, minContextSlot });
        
              const confirmtx = await connection.confirmTransaction({ blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight, signature });
              console.log({ signature, confirmtx });

        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
```

The tx pops up, and after confirming it, I get these 2 similar errors:
1.

**Phantom - RPC Error: Signature verification failed {code: -32003, message: 'Signature verification failed'}**

2.

**WalletSendTransactionError: Signature verification failed
at PhantomWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.ts:223:23)
at async WalletProviderBase.tsx:201:20
at async SignIn (Profile.jsx:101:31)**

Any ideas what is the reasoning? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `nonceAccount` to your signers, since you're creating it in this transaction. So when sending the transaction, try:

```
              const signature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection, {
                minContextSlot,
                skipPreflight: true,
                signers: [nonceAccount],
                preflightCommitment: 'processed',
              });
```